# Regular expression for matching alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a CLI where the user can declare an alphabet and pass it to my code. My code generate a string with that alphabet

For example if the user declare these groups of alphabet `abc` `abcAB1234` and `@#1$2%` I need to generate a string where every single character is at least in one group and the generated string has all the characters defined by the alphabet. No repetition are allowed (case sensitive)

So, if the alphabet is `abc` `abcAB1234` `@#1$2%` the admitted output can be `B#1a` or `@ca41%` but not `aA#@` (same character 'a' repeated) or `aBcZ#` ('Z' is not part of the alphabet) or `aBA43` (some characters of alphabet are not presents)

I tried with this `^(?!.*([abcabcAB1234@#1$2%])\1{1})(?!.*([abc])\1{1})(?!.*([abcAB1234])\1{1})(?!.*([@#1$2%])\1{1})[abcabcAB1234@#1$2%]{8,}$` but, obviously, doesn't work

Can someone please help me to understand where I'm wrong with my regexp?

Comment: Pretty sure regex isn't powerful enough to manage this. At least not a single regexp.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with a RexExp. But it is easy to achieve using a `Set`.

```js
const alphabet = 'abcBEL'

const wordToMatch = 'BLa'
const wordToMatch2 = 'BLaa'
const wordToMatch3 = 'zBLa'

function checkWord(alphabet, word) {
  const set = new Set(alphabet.split(''))
  
  for (const c of word){
    if (!set.has(c)) return false
    set.delete(c)
  }
  return true
}

console.log(checkWord(alphabet, wordToMatch))
console.log(checkWord(alphabet, wordToMatch2))
console.log(checkWord(alphabet, wordToMatch3))
```

Comment: I don't think that Sets are that I need because in your example in the set the alphabet is `abcEL` excluding the uppercase B because it is already present in lowercase. But I want to mantain the original alphabet. Anyway I understand the process and maybe one regexp is a little bit complicated